# How to sort hash keys based on array keys?

Tags: ruby

There is an example of a hash:

```rb
h1 = {
  a1: :a2,
  b1: :b2,
  c1: :c2,
  d1: :d2,
  e1: :e2,
  f1: :f2
}
```

And there is such an array of keys:

```rb
a1 = [:b1, :d1, :f1]
```

How to sort the keys of this hash based on the array? The hash keys that are not in the array must come after the sorted ones in the order in which they were.

Result:

```rb
{
  b1: :b2,
  d1: :d2,
  f1: :f2,
  a1: :a2,
  c1: :c2,
  e1: :e2
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this:

```
h1.slice(*a1).merge(h1.except(*a1))
#=> {:b1=>:b2, :d1=>:d2, :f1=>:f2, :a1=>:a2, :c1=>:c2, :e1=>:e2}
```

[`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-slice) returns the elements from `h1` in the order how they are defined in `a1`. And the [`Hash#except`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-except) returns the missing ones. And [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge) merges both groups into one hash.

Comment: ...or just `h1.slice(*a1).merge(h1)`.

Answer (score 4):

You may write

```
h1.slice(*a1, *(h1.keys - a1))
```

or

```
h1.slice(*a1, *h1.keys)
```

Both return

```
{:b1=>:b2, :d1=>:d2, :f1=>:f2, :a1=>:a2, :c1=>:c2, :e1=>:e2}
```

See [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).